# select values based on condition using .Include in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to return only those answers whose aapprove value is 1.
Here is my Answer.cs :

```
public partial class Answer
    {
        public int aid { get; set; }
        public string abody { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> adate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> alikes { get; set; }
        public int uid { get; set; }
        public int qid { get; set; }
        public int Question_qid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> aapprove { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Question.cs :

```
public partial class Question
    {

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Question()
        {
            this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
        }

        public int qid { get; set; }
        public string qtitle { get; set; }
        public string qbody { get; set; }
        public string qtags { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> qlikes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> qcomments { get; set; }
        public int uid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> qdate { get; set; }
        public int User_uid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> qapprove { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller, I am doing,

```
List<Question> questions = entities.Questions
                    .Include("Answers")
                    .Where(q => q.qapprove == 1)
                    .ToList();
```

This is returning array like :

```
 {
        "qid": 1,
        "qtitle": "What is the fees of xyz college",
        "qbody": "I wanted to know the fees of xyz MBBS college. Please help if any one knows.",
        "qtags": "FEES",
        "qlikes": 1,
        "qcomments": 14,
        "uid": 1,
        "qdate": "2017-03-12T04:35:00",
        "User_uid": 1,
        "qapprove": 1,
        "Answers": [
            {
                "aid": 1,
                "abody": "The fees of this college is not very high. Average people can manage easily.",
                "adate": "2017-01-02T04:35:00",
                "alikes": 15,
                "uid": 1,
                "qid": 1,
                "Question_qid": 1,
                "aapprove": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to return only those answers whose aapprove value is 1.(Include("Answers") is returning all the answers which I don't want).How can I do this?

Comment: Use select instead, load your answers into an anonymous type ef will attach everything

Comment: It would be great help if you specify with the code also. That will be much helpful.

Comment: question array can have more than one answers. How would I select those answers whose aapprove is 1?

Comment: see my answer below this should satisfy the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select to load you data and entity framework will take care of attaching

```
var data = entities.Questions
                .Include("Answers")
                .Where(q => q.qapprove == 1)
                .Select(x => new { Questions = x, Answers = 
                                               x.Answers.Where(a => /*Your condition*/)})
                .ToList();

var questions = data.Select(x => x.Questions).ToList();
```

Comment: Can anyone explain this part? Never used this before :


.Select(x => new { Questions = x, Answers = 
                                               x.Answers.Where(a => /*Your condition*/)})

Comment: Basically this is select the questions and answers, except you can filter your answers.  They are both pulled into the context. EF sees that these entities are related and attaches them in the context so that when you only have the questions the answers are attached as well

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it from other side

```
var questions = entities.Answers
                        .Where(answer => answer.aapprove == 1)
                        .GroupBy(answer => answer.Question_qid)
                        .Select(group => new {
                            Question = group.First().Question,
                            Answers = group;
                        });
```